transition circleclose is not working in FFMPEG
wanted to add circleclose transition to 2 videos while adding. transition effect is not coming. What is the issue in below FFMPEG command?
    ffmpeg -i D:/development/copy/UKKT0069595Min_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_1_4345.mp4 -i D:/development/copy/UKKT0069595Min_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_2_9469.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]xfade=transition=circleclose:duration=0.5:offset=5.5,format=yuv420p[video];[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio]" -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -movflags +faststart D:/development/copy/video_5370_circleclose.mp4

My video length is as below

UKKT0069595Min_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_1_4345.mp4 is 6 sec (00:06)

UKKT0069595Min_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_2_9469.mp4 is 10 sec (00:10)

**output with -report command below:**

D:\softwares\ffmpeg-2024-06-30-git-b818dff8d8-full_build\bin>ffmpeg -i D:/development/copy/UKKT0069595Min_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_1_4345.mp4 -i D:/development/copy/UKKT0069595Min_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_2_9469.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]xfade=transition=circleclose:duration=0.5:offset=5.5,format=yuv420p[video];[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio]" -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -movflags +faststart D:/development/copy/video_5370_circleclose23.mp4 -report

ffmpeg started on 2024-07-03 at 10:02:46
Report written to "ffmpeg-20240703-100246.log"
Log level: 48

ffmpeg version 2024-06-30-git-b818dff8d8-full_build-www.gyan.dev 
Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)

  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libquirc --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libxevd --enable-libzvbi --enable-libqrencode --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libvvenc --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxeve --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-d3d12va --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-libvpl --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-vaapi --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavcodec     61.  9.100 / 61.  9.100
  libavformat    61.  4.100 / 61.  4.100
  libavdevice    61.  2.100 / 61.  2.100
  libavfilter    10.  2.102 / 10.  2.102
  libswscale      8.  2.100 /  8.  2.100
  libswresample   5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libpostproc    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/development/copy/UKKT0069595Min_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_1_4345.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.65.101
  Duration: 00:00:06.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 18457 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 18134 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 316 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/development/copy/UKKT0069595Min_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_2_9469.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.65.101
  Duration: 00:00:10.90, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 21762 kb/s
  Stream #1:0[0x1](eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 21433 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #1:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 321 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> xfade
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> acrossfade
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> xfade
  Stream #1:1 (aac) -> acrossfade
  format:default -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  acrossfade:default -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 000001a8cc79f040] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 000001a8cc79f040] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 000001a8cc79f040] profile High, level 4.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000001a8cc79f040] 264 - core 164 r3191 4613ac3 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2024 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00

Output #0, mp4, to 'D:/development/copy/video_5370_circleclose23.mp4':
  
Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom

    minor_version   : 512

    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41

    encoder         : Lavf61.4.100


  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 25 fps, 12800 tbn

      Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavc61.9.100 libx264

      Side data:

        cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s

      Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavc61.9.100 aac

[mp4 @ 000001a8cc090900] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file

[out#0/mp4 @ 000001a8cba3dbc0] video:10314KiB audio:257KiB subtitle:0KiB other streams:0KiB global headers:0KiB muxing overhead: 0.129418%

frame=  411 fps= 21 q=-1.0 Lsize=   10585KiB time=00:00:16.36 bitrate=5300.4kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.832x

[libx264 @ 000001a8cc79f040] frame I:2     Avg QP:20.98  size:210394

[libx264 @ 000001a8cc79f040] frame P:103   Avg QP:22.71  size: 70959
[libx264 @ 000001a8cc79f040] frame B:306   Avg QP:27.55  size:  9253

[libx264 @ 000001a8cc79f040] consecutive B-frames:  0.5%  0.5%  0.7% 98.3%


[libx264 @ 000001a8cc79f040] mb I  I16..4: 12.7% 52.9% 34.4%

[libx264 @ 000001a8cc79f040] mb P  I16..4:  4.7%  5.9%  0.9%  P16..4: 54.3% 20.2% 10.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 3.7%

[libx264 @ 000001a8cc79f040] mb B  I16..4:  0.3%  0.4%  0.0%  B16..8: 50.9%  1.7%  0.2%  direct: 1.9%  skip:44.5%  L0:48.1% L1:46.5% BI: 5.4%

[libx264 @ 000001a8cc79f040] 8x8 transform intra:51.7% inter:68.7%
[libx264 @ 000001a8cc79f040] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 40.2% 84.9% 32.0% inter: 15.3% 30.0% 2.3%

[libx264 @ 000001a8cc79f040] i16 v,h,dc,p: 34% 29% 18% 19%

[libx264 @ 000001a8cc79f040] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 28% 20% 26%  4%  4%  5%  4%  4%  5%

[libx264 @ 000001a8cc79f040] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 33% 20% 12%  5%  7%  7%  6%  6%  5%

[libx264 @ 000001a8cc79f040] i8c dc,h,v,p: 40% 23% 27% 11%

[libx264 @ 000001a8cc79f040] Weighted P-Frames: Y:12.6% UV:3.9%

[libx264 @ 000001a8cc79f040] ref P L0: 59.1% 16.1% 18.9%  5.1%  0.8%

[libx264 @ 000001a8cc79f040] ref B L0: 93.0%  6.1%  0.9%

[libx264 @ 000001a8cc79f040] ref B L1: 95.6%  4.4%

[libx264 @ 000001a8cc79f040] kb/s:5139.20

[aac @ 000001a8cc6a0480] Qavg: 802.393



D:\softwares\ffmpeg-2024-06-30-git-b818dff8d8-full_build\bin>


Rerun with -report and share report.

output with -report command is added in the main question. Please advise.

Is there any way where I can share my sample video's. Please advise the solution.

Yes ,upload them somewhere and share links here.

please see the url, I have uploaded the video:  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kqsevmBUWm2pv69QJuZ1ASlGDnXXXzGq

It's working fine but you can't clearly notice it when both clips are very similar - same subject with same camera just at different times. Pick some other transition.

thankyou so much, its working now!
